# Android best way to switch language on run-time

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm looking for a nice way in Android to change the language of an app on run-time (meaning, I wish to press a button to change strings from language A to language B without losing the current navigation, state, user input, etc).
So far I have only found a way to do it which requires a restart of the activity, but since I'm running a single activity architecture, this will restart the entire app, which is not ideal.

So, can anyone propose some ways to handle this in Android?

Comment: This article can help you
https://medium.com/swlh/android-app-specific-language-change-programmatically-using-kotlin-d650a5392220

Comment: The whole activity is reloaded on a screen rotation anyway.  Probably simpler to just let it happen, since you already have to design things to be restored.

Answer (score 0):

```
    val languageToLoad = "en" // your language fr etc

    val locale = Locale(languageToLoad)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config = Configuration()
    config.locale = locale
    baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(
        config,
        baseContext.resources.displayMetrics
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but won't this require the entire activity to be reloaded and hence losing the current state?

Comment: you also save the current state before change the language same like rotate android phone  : explantation-- Android calls onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) as a way for the developer to save/restore state. When the activity is destroyed via back button or finish(), onSaveInstanceState is not called and the savedInstanceState bundle that's passed to onCreate() is nul

Comment: So that would mean that I need to save all current content in the UI to the bundle? 
And how to I trigger the activity restart then?

Answer (score 0):

Me, in the apps I use an external library called 'dev.b3nedikt.reword: reword'

in build.gradle file:

```
 implementation 'dev.b3nedikt.viewpump:viewpump:4.0.7'
    implementation 'dev.b3nedikt.reword:reword:4.0.0'
    implementation 'dev.b3nedikt.applocale:applocale:2.0.3'
```

github repo:
https://github.com/B3nedikt/reword

Comment: I'll look into this repo, thanks!